# Extract multiple factors in Indeed HTML tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract multiple factors from each of the repeated tags in a HTML file.

....

```
<div class="title">
    <a target="_blank" id="jl_fe575975c912af9e" href="https://www.indeed.com/company/Nestvestor/jobs/Data-Science-Intern-fe575975c912af9e?fccid=8eed076a625928e7&amp;vjs=3" onmousedown="return rclk(this,jobmap[0],0);" onclick=" setRefineByCookie(['radius']); return rclk(this,jobmap[0],true,0);" rel="noopener nofollow" title="Data Science Intern" class="jobtitle turnstileLink " data-tn-element="jobTitle">
        Data Science Intern</a>

    </div>

<div class="sjcl">
    <div>
<span class="company">
    Nestvestor</span>

</div>
```

```
<div class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard" id="p_9cfaca3374641aa0" data-jk="9cfaca3374641aa0" data-tn-component="organicJob">

<div class="title">
    <a target="_blank" id="jl_9cfaca3374641aa0" href="https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=9cfaca3374641aa0&amp;fccid=1779658d5b4ae2b0&amp;vjs=3" onmousedown="return rclk(this,jobmap[1],0);" onclick=" setRefineByCookie(['radius']); return rclk(this,jobmap[1],true,0);" rel="noopener nofollow" title="Product Manager" class="jobtitle turnstileLink " data-tn-element="jobTitle">
        Product Manager</a>

    </div>

<div class="sjcl">
    <div>
<span class="company">
    <a data-tn-element="companyName" class="turnstileLink" target="_blank" href="https://www.indeed.com/cmp/Sojern" onmousedown="this.href = appendParamsOnce(this.href, 'from=SERP&amp;campaignid=serp-linkcompanyname&amp;fromjk=9cfaca3374641aa0&amp;jcid=1779658d5b4ae2b0')" rel="noopener">
    Sojern</a></span>
```

...

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(input("Enter a file to read: ")), "html.parser")


title = soup.find_all('div', class_='title')
for span in title:
    print(span.text)

company = soup.find_all('span', class_='company')
for span in company:
    print(span.text)
```

So far I have figured out how to get the following result:

Job_Title1

Job_Title2

Job_Title3

And in a different code result:

Company_name1

Company_Name2

Company_Name3

How do I get the results to look look like this with one run of code:
Job_Title1,Company_Name1,
Job_Title2,Company_Name2,
Job_Title3,Company_Name3,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow,Just use this:

```
company = soup.find_all('span', class_='company')
title = soup.find_all('div', class_='title')
for t,c  in zip(title, company): 
print ("Job_Title :%s Company_Name :%s" %(t.text,c.text))
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, thank you. Where could I find more information on 'zip' and the use of ':%s'. I don't really understand their use.

Comment: The result for this did not give me the text but the whole tag code instead for some reason.

Comment: Here check this out [zip](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/amp/&ved=2ahUKEwj8u9mdz7PjAhUjSo8KHSCpCN0QFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1V5mPYh-TP5XBjMh_XonXw&ampcf=1) and [String formatting](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting)

Comment: Thank you @Ankit Agrawal , how do I look into learning more about this: `("Job_Title :%s Company_Name :%s" %(t.text,c.text))`

Answer (score 0):

From what you have it looks like you need to nest your loops. Without the website, it is hard to tell but I would try something like this.

```
    company = soup.find_all('span', class_='company')
    title = soup.find_all('div', class_='title')
    for span in title:
        for x in company:
   print(x.text,span.text)
```

Comment: Hi Michael, this worked! The result is repeating different versions for some reason.

Comment: Obviously it will print 9 results instead of 3 because of the structure of for loops @OscarEvolves

Comment: The only problem I had using this is when I added a `.append(str())` statement I had to split the print statement. i.e.     `for span in jobTitle:

        for x in companyName:
            comps_and_jobs.append(str(x.text))
            comps_and_jobs.append(str(span.text))
    return comps_and_jobs`